# InfoPath The InfoPath form template for the selected content type cannot be loaded

Tags: 2010, web-part, infopath

I'm trying to add an InfoPath webpart to a page but I get the following error.

```
The InfoPath form template for the selected content type cannot be loaded.
```

The document library on `SiteB` has infopath documents pointing to another library in `SiteA`. `SiteA` is able to display the form while `SiteB` can not. Is the issue because it's on a different site?

Comment: Are you face this issue after migration ?

Comment: This is after a migration, both `SiteA` and `SiteB` were migrated. But I believe this is the first time `SiteB` is attempting to point to the `SiteA` infopath list.

Comment: are you checked this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbf4d29a-4af1-46ae-81e6-c1d02464e91a/getting-error-the-infopath-form-template-for-the-selected-content-type-cannot-be-loaded-the-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `User Browser-enabled Form Templates` by doing the following :

- Go to Central Administration > General Application Settings > Configure InfoPath Forms Services check

  - Allow users to browser-enable form templates.
  - Render form templates that are browser-enabled by user

For more details check [The InfoPath form template for the selected content type cannot be loaded. The form template was not designed for InfoPath Forms Services and cannot be rendered in the browser.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbf4d29a-4af1-46ae-81e6-c1d02464e91a/getting-error-the-infopath-form-template-for-the-selected-content-type-cannot-be-loaded-the-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

also , check the compatability at  InfoPath Designer 2013 as the following :

- Open your Form in InfoPath Designer 2013. Go to File->Form Options-> Compatibility
- Change the mode from Web Browser Form (InfoPath 2010) to Web Browser Form, save and quick publish your form.

For more details check : ["The InfoPath form template for the selected content type cannot be loaded"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/victorbutuza/2014/01/16/the-infopath-form-template-for-the-selected-content-type-cannot-be-loaded/)

Comment: Yes, but for the Central Admin change, I do not have permissions to it. I was assuming that because it works on `SiteA` that it will be activated on `SiteB`.

Comment: okay are you checked compatibility at InfoPath Designer 2013

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this is 2010